# Finding index where string 2 starts in string 1

Tags: java, string

So I am writing a program with multiple different methods, and one of the methods asks to find the index where the second strings starts in the first string

The method accepts two strings as parameters and returns the character index of the position where the second string begins in the first. for example:

**IN**: `legos, go`

**OUT**: `2`

The catch of this method is that I can only use `charAt`, `substring` and `length` from the `String` class, and no other class methods

I have no code currently, I need an idea on how to start it

EDIT: Thanks for the help, now instead of looking for the index of where the second string starts, i want to find the index of where the second string starts in the rightmost area of the first string. for example

IN: mississippi, ss
OUT: 5

Thanks in advance

Comment: As I can understand find second word that contain go for example?

Comment: This method should look into string 1 for string 2, and it outputs the index of the first string where the second string started

Comment: If you want code that performs an entirely different function, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int indexOf(final String source, final String find) {
    // loop from first character to last character that still leaves length of 'find' string available
    for(int sourcePos = 0; sourcePos < source.length() - find.length(); sourcePos++) {
        boolean found = true;
        for(int findPos = 0; findPos < find.length(); findPos++) {
            // if the current char is not a match, then mark as not found and break from loop
            if(source.charAt(sourcePos) != find.charAt(findPos)) {
                found = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found) {
            return sourcePos;
        }
    }

    // return -1 to indicate the string was not found
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This solution seems to be working for me thanks, one question though, what if now instead if finding where it starts, i want to find where it appears in the rightmost position

Comment: Change the first for loop to `for(int sourcePos = source.length() - find.length() - 1; sourcePos >= 0; sourcePos--) {`

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Say your Strings are `s1` and `s2`. Try every index of `s1` in order, and see at each of these indexes if there is a substring of `s1` of length `s2.length()` that is exactly `s2`.

Comment: OP can't use `.equals()`

Comment: Well then I guess he'd have to test for equality manually using charAt and a for loop. How is that in conflict with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly straightforward approach that should meet your requirements. Start by writing a `main()` method to test your method. Let's call it `indexOf` because that's the function we're going to implement. We need to get the length of both `String`(s), I suggest we do it outside of the loop body. Then we need an inner loop to start whenever we find a `char` that matches. If the second length matches the inner loop index we have a match and `return`. Finally, (if no matches found) `return -1` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(indexOf("legos", "go"));
}

static int indexOf(String str, String toFind) {
    // Length of both String(s).
    int len = (str != null) ? str.length() : 0;
    int len2 = (toFind != null) ? toFind.length() : 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int t = 0;
        while (str.charAt(i) == toFind.charAt(t) 
                && i < len && t < len2) {
            t++;
            i++;
        }
        i -= t; // <-- reset position to start of match finding position.
        if (t == len2) {
            return i; // <-- match found.
        }
    }
    // No match. Default return.
    return -1;
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
2
```